# Removing starting gl- using rename

Tags: rename

I have a list of files, for instance

```
./2020/47-06/gl-086115.org
./2020/47-06/gl-085792.org
./2020/47-06/gl-086941.org
./2020/47-06/gl-087140.pdf
./2020/47-06/gl-085982.pdf
./2020/47-06/gl-087032.org
./2020/47-06/gl-086115.pdf
./2020/47-06/gl-087490.pdf
```

I am using the following command to remove the beginning `gl-`, without success.

```
find . -type f -name '*gl-*' -exec rename 's/^gl-//g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, needing `-d`:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*gl-*' -exec rename -n -d 's/^gl-//' {} \;
rename(./2020/47-06/gl-087032.org, ./2020/47-06/087032.org)
rename(./2020/47-06/gl-086941.org, ./2020/47-06/086941.org)
rename(./2020/47-06/gl-087140.pdf, ./2020/47-06/087140.pdf)
rename(./2020/47-06/gl-085792.org, ./2020/47-06/085792.org)
rename(./2020/47-06/gl-085982.pdf, ./2020/47-06/085982.pdf)
rename(./2020/47-06/gl-086115.org, ./2020/47-06/086115.org)
rename(./2020/47-06/gl-086115.pdf, ./2020/47-06/086115.pdf)
rename(./2020/47-06/gl-087490.pdf, ./2020/47-06/087490.pdf)
```

`man rename`:

> -d, --filename, --nopath, --nofullpath
> Do not rename directory: only rename filename component of path.

#### If you don't have `-d` switch

```
find ./2020/ -type f -name '*gl-*' -exec rename -n 's|/gl-|/|g' {} +
```

But take care to not have any other occurrence of `gl-` in the path.

A safer way would be:

```
find ./2020 -type f -name '*gl-*' -exec bash -c '
    cd $(dirname "$1")
    rename -n "s/gl-//" ./"$1"
' bash {} \;
```

Drop `-n` when happy with the output.

Comment: I do not see the `-d` option in `info rename`.

Comment: Because you have a different version of `rename`

Comment: I can see a `-e` option.  Expression: code to act on files name.

Comment: Could one use `-exec rename 's/\/gl-/\//g' {} \;`

Comment: Added another way, without `-d`

Comment: Solution that changes the separator.